# Trying to highlight passed days in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

i have a google spreadsheet document with dates on the left rows:

- 1.1.2016
- 2.1.2016
- .....

i want to highlight days that have already passed, and i have got this code:

```
function myFunction() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetSelect = ss.getSheetByName("test");
  var todayis = getCell(1,12);

  {
    for(var i = 0; i<sheetSelect.getMaxRows();i++)
    {
      if (getCell(i,1) == todayis)
      {
        var changeRange = sheetSelect.getRange(i,1);
        changeRange.setBackgroundRGB(111, 111, 222);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not working, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a less-complicated way to do it:

1. Right click on the cells you want to conditionally highlight.
2. Click "Conditional Formatting" from the right-click menu.
3. Under "Format cells if...", select "Date is before"
4. In the next drop-down select "today"
5. Select the background color you want.
6. Click "Done"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a google apps script also if your dates are all formatted into text as it shows in your example you can use the conditional formatting with a custom formula - highlight the column you want, choose conditional formatting and enter in this formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(DATEVALUE(substitute(A1:A,".","/"))<today(),true,false))
```